# Local Docker Compose exited abnormally with code 1 whilst running command: up -d

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, docker, containers

I am trying to create test container with `DockerComposeContainer`.

```
DockerComposeContainer container =
                  new DockerComposeContainer(
                          new File("src/integrationTest/resources/mycompose-file.yml"))
                      .withLocalCompose(true)
                      .withExposedService("mongodb", 27017, Wait.forListeningPort());
              container.start();
              return container;
```

`mycopose-file.yml` has following:

```
version: '3'

services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:3.6
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: uname
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: upass
```

My test dependency include:  `testcontainers-1.12.3.jar`

I am getting error during application context startup:
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext`

with root cause:

```
Caused by: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Local Docker Compose exited abnormally with code 1 whilst running command: up -d
    at org.testcontainers.containers.LocalDockerCompose.invoke(DockerComposeContainer.java:711)
....
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case I got this error because network in docker had exhausted. Given docker has limited network that we can have. We have to do the cleanup, for that I ran command:

`docker network prune`

this fixed my problem